# Implementing TCP packet sniffer using raw sockets in Go

Tags: sockets, go, network-programming, packet-sniffers, sniffer

I am looking for a way to listen on an interface for all incoming traffic using the Go programming language.

I would want it to be something similar to this python:

```
import socket, sys
from struct import *
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65565)
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You may like to check https://github.com/buger/gor for reference, and https://github.com/buger/gor/blob/master/raw_socket_listener/listener.go#L595 in particular.

Comment: Slawosz, those are both great examples. Thanks. However, I'm looking for something that will allow to parse the packet use dns queries identified in the packet. We have a tap from a remote interface that is pushing packets to my interface, and I'm attempting to accept them and pull them apart. I've used Python Scapy and the amount of packets we have coming in are too many for Scapy to handle.

Comment: Go can do raw sockets just fine. [This search](https://www.google.com/search?q=raw+socket+golang) should get you up to speed with examples. Oh, and you could find [this library](https://github.com/miekg/dns) useful if you want to parse DNS stuff from its wire format -- it provides for advanced processing of in plain Go.

Comment: You might also be tempted to use something like `gopacket` which wraps dissecting libraries provided by `tcpdump` and Wireshark but you must keep in mind that calling C from Go is *slow* -- possibly slower than performing a syscall, so if performance is of paramount importance steer clear from wrapped C libraries and make sure you're using pure Go.

Comment: Roger. Thanks for the feedback and help.